# SQL Server MDF file is smaller than expected

Tags: sql-server, windows, mdf

I'm executing very large SQL files (100-200 GBs) to import data into SQL Server on a Windows 10 computer. Execution is going well with no errors so far but disk usage is much lower than I expect it to be.

For example I executed 3 SQL files full of inserts with about 50 GBs of total size but SQL Server is showing that 6.5 GB is used by the database. Is this normal or is there something funny going on?

Disk is a 1 TB NVME M2 SSD.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That the file was 100GB doesn't mean that the database will be. The size of a text file and the database are not comparable. *Assuming* a good design, you will be using appropriate data types for your data, so (for example), an integer value like `1234567324` will be stored as a 4 byte `int`, but in your text file, it would likely be stored as a string and could be as large as *20 bytes* in size. Not to mention things like compression, etc.

Comment: Of course but the difference seems too much to me, i'm wondering if i'm losing data along the way. Asking here just to be sure.

Comment: When you say your file is full of inserts do you mean that your file has the insert statements or the data that is being inserted?

Comment: *"Disk is a 1TB NVME M2 SSD"* This also means very little, in truth. A 1TB NVME M2 SSD can be very slow (SATA speeds) if all that data is on 1 or 2 chips and the device has no DRAM.

Comment: @SeanLange full of inserts and GO statements every 100 inserts.

Comment: *"the difference seems too much to me"* We can't see your SQL, or your data. As a *overly* simplified example, assume you have ~1 million `INSERT` statements with something like `INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (MyInteger) VALUES (1000000);` all the way to `INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (MyInteger) VALUES (1999999);`. *IF* we assume the text file is ANSI or UTF so each character is a byte and you use CRLF for each line that's 55 bytes per line for a total of ~55,000,000 bytes. An `int` is 4 bytes, which would mean the table is ~4,000,000 bytes in size; literally over 10 times smaller.

Comment: Well then you can't even pretend to compare the disc usage. All the text creating the insert statements is going to be massive. Likely 50% or more of the information in your text file is the insert statements not the data.

Comment: `SQL Server is showing` -> where are you looking at this? Keep in mind that some metadata gets cached so what you see in some flaky dialog somewhere in the UI might not be accurate. But yeah, a file containing DML does not mean the table storing the _result_ of those statements will be the same size. There's not really a reason you should expect that.

Comment: Alright thank you both. I'll compare record counts and see if there is any data missing.

Comment: Why are you executing such scripts in the first place instead of restoring a backup or importing data files? A dump file isn't a backup, it's a script. It will always be several times larger than the actual data. Not only does a script include commands, and column names, but `123` requires 3 characters even though it only needs 1 byte in the data file

Comment: A naïve script that executes one `INSERT` per row would take at least twice the space of the text values alone, because it repeats the column list. Unlike real backups, those INSERTS are fully logged operations that get written to the transaction log. That's very slow too. Real backups and restores work at the data page level though and don't involve the transaction log. Finally, unlike dumps, taking a backup is transparent to users

Comment: Some database products that *don't* have real backups talk about "logical" backups and claim some non-existent "portability" advantages. Those aren't backups and there are no portability advantages. You can't load a PostgreSQL dump into MySQL without encountering problems due to type and feature differences. You may have problems loading the same dump into different versions of the same database

Comment: Are you using columnstore indexes?